# Should I delete downvoted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

People keep downvoting my question even when it has valuable answers.

- Should I delete the question?
- Can I report downvoters? There seems to be at least some decent users answering adding valuable information.

Comment: “Should I delete the question?” -No, Asking a question then deleting it is one of the quickest ways to become question banned. Just **edit** your questions and improve them. “can I report downvoters.” - All voting activity (downvote and upvote) is anonymous. So it’s impossible to report downvoters. In fact reporting a downvoter would be considered to be a hostile toxic activity. Due to the vagueness of this question. I have downvoted your question. **Please be respectful of all users.** My other communities are hidden. I will be watching for retaliatory downvoting (which isn’t allowed)

Comment: As to the reason I mentioned retaliatory downvoting, I have fallen victim to that activity, numerous times (more than 10 times) by Stack Overflow users who are critical of downvoters.

Comment: downvoting is really too cheap. Downvoting without comment should cost more than downvoting without.

Comment: @SecurityHound downvoting _without_  good reason is __more__ toxic IMHO. It kills quality. Uncommenting downvoters are _disrespectful_

Comment: Anonymous voting *is* the model used here, and Stack overflow *has* been successful, so that is sort of a proof that it works. I can certainly understand why that's unsatisfactory to someone who's been downvoted.

Comment: Before this get too much out of hand: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr

Comment: @theking2 you, like many others, understandably mistake  SO as like a social media platform where downvotes are given to people they don’t like or want to hurt in some way. This isn’t how it works. They are used to signpost the quality of a question and notify others users whether it’s worth reading a question or answer.

Comment: @theking2 - upvoting without good reason is more toxic IMHO. It kills legitimate quality. Uncommenting upvoters are disrespectful. After being a victim of serial downvoting at my primary community due to a comment made against multiple SO user’s comment and they happen to have enough reputation to downvote ALL my question(s) at that other community my feelings towards downvoting is heavily swayed. I have reported the behavior. at times the serial downvoting went undetected by the script due to being stretched over days. No; thanks on the required feedback.

Comment: @theking2 "downvoting is really too cheap" and yet ***VASTLY*** underused. Also, used a lot less than upvotes. "*Uncommenting downvoters are disrespectful*" and users hurling abuse *at commenters* are a lot more than just "disrespectful". They are rude, they are abusive, they are actually toxic. Not in the meaning where you're using it but the real one. One easy way to avoid the toxicity is to avoid commenting to not be a target. However, then **you** (and others like you) accuse users of being "toxic" by not commenting (also, by not actually understanding "toxic"). It's a lose-lose.

Comment: "can I report downvoters." for future reference, that is the toxic behaviour downvoters (and not only) want to avoid by not commenting. I often start writing a comment and just abort it if a question gets a downvote in the mean time. I do not want to deal with the fallout any more. Many post authors act as if their post is the best thing in the world and anybody they *think* has downvoted deserves some punishment. I mean, we have the evidence here by you. Why in the world would anybody want to risk being "reported". Whatever you think that should do would be bad for whoever is reported.

Comment: we don't vote without a good reason. We vote because of the quality of question. good=upvote, bad=downvote. Your assumptions are more toxic and disrespectful towards the time people spend to help curate this site.

Comment: @Alvi15 I spend a lot of time curate this site. Please explain where and why I was disrespectful.

Comment: @theking2 It is disrespectful to pressure, push, shame, attempt to persecute, or throw baseless accusations of toxicity towards voters because of their right to remain anonymous and vote without leaving any comments in the process (as you did [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422371/should-i-delete-downvoted-questions#comment940804_422371)).

Answer (score 20):

> Should I delete the question?

No, the question should be improved so it is up to par. (if the question has an upvoted answer you can no longer delete the question. That is to prevent we lose valuable content).

> Can I report downvoters?

No. You don't need to report me. Everybody knows who I am. I'm free to use my votes as I see fit. Downvoting posts that are deemed not useful is a key feature of the question and answer model as designed by Stack Overflow. Other models give you Yahoo! Answers. One of those will do.

Comment: What if the question cannot be improved to fit site guidelines?

Comment: “What if the question cannot be improved to fit site guidelines?” - If a contribution can be improved to meet the guidelines of the community, then the community should delete it, as that’s an indication it should have never been submitted. Asking out of scope questions isn’t allowed and is another reason for question bans. *Questions that are out of scope are often deleted and closed, closed downvoted questions, are eligible for automatic deletion* Deleted questions, downvoted questions, and questions that don’t receive any votes are the primary reasons for users being questioned banned.

Comment: @BlueRobin It does take multiple questions to get into a question ban. Not just one. I suggest not posting multiple irredeemable questions. Maybe one or two if you really want to but try not to go overboard.

Comment: @BlueRobin It's a common misconception that you need to **post** questions here to get answers. In fact, I'd say it's a lot harder to write a good question, than it is to write a good answer. The nice thing is, that in vast majority of cases someone already asked about a similar problem and a bunch of people already provided useful solutions.

Comment: @DanMašek True. I wish I knew that a lot earlier.